# How to retrieve the SKU of the first simple product for a configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product, google-tag-manager

I am trying to retrieve the SKU of the first simple product of configurable product as soon as a certain SKU type is found to be "configurable" type. The code below helps find out if the main SKU is configurable or not. I need to find out the SKU of the first simple product of this configurable product. Please advice.

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
 echo 'This is a configurable product';
 // I need to retrieve the SKU of the first simple product for this configurable product and return the SKU
}else{
 echo 'This is not a configurable product';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
$_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductCollection($_product)->getFirstItem()->getSku()
```

Comment: let me try and let you know.

Comment: Hi, getting this error when used your code: Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::getUsedProductsCollection()

Comment: sorry, typo. method should be: `->getUsedProductCollection()` (without "s")

Comment: No problem, I think we are getting close to the solution. This error comes up. Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::getUsedProductCollection(), 0 passed in

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot and am too grateful to express it. It resolved my issue thus saving a lot of time.